# Adding Forms Authentication to ASP.Net project results in 401.2 Unauthorized?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I am trying to retrospectively plug in Forms Authentication to an ASP.Net project that was originally created with the no authentication template using VS 2013 and ASP.Net 4.0

I have followed the advice on MSDN and added this to my Web Config under system.web

```
 <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="Logon.aspx" name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH">
      </forms>
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
```

When I launch the site (IIS 7) the URL redirects to the Logon.aspx page but then I get a  **Error message 401.2.: Unauthorized: Logon failed due to server configuration.**

In IIS I have the website set for Anonymous and Forms based authentication enabled.

Am I missing something here? I think there might be a hidden setting somewhere that ASP.net sets when he no authentication template is used?

**Edit**: The issue is the same as reported here:  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/2920a4e2-775a-4aa7-bfff-4931fa0a4e9a/azure-website-forms-authentication-issue?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview

It looks like there is an issue with Forms authentication not working with ASP.net template projects. :(. It works fine with the "Empty ASP.Net web application" but any of the others runs into this issue.

Answer (score 3):

If using friendly url ( just remove the .aspx from the loginUrl in web.config)

Change the web.config file Authentication.
In this case it will be

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="Logon" name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH">
      </forms>
</authentication>
```

Answer (score 1):

After much digging the answer is to remove the Friendly URLS Nuget that comes with the ASP.net templates.